# How to make fit image in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, layout, android-gridview

I am trying to make menu board, in which i am using `gridview`, I want to make 4 row visible to every android device to make avoid user from scrolling. 
Here is my layout for `imageview`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_icon_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/launcher_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="9sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my `gridview` xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tech.reader.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:numColumns="3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my image what is currently looks

[image: current image]

and what i want is

[image]

and what image size i use , which works on every android device.

Thanks

Comment: By the way, you don't need the LinearLayout and the ImageView. Just use a **compound drawable** in the TextView. This would result in a **flatter layout** (which means **better performances**).

Answer (score 0):

i think just use `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` to `android:scaleType="fitXY"` or `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` hpe so will work fine for you.
 enjoy your code time:)

Comment: see https://caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html hope so will get help